# Prevent people from reverse-engineering my network protocol

Tags: c#, security, networking, obfuscation

I know I cant **prevent** people from reverse-engineering my protocol but I'd like to take a security-through-obscurity approach to make it as hard as possible.

I have a server/client system that communicates through the network with `http` style packets.

Example:

```
Header
Attribute: Value
Attribute2: Other Value

Payload
```

I would like to make it as hard as possible for anything other than my client to access the network. Pushing problems with them decompiling my assemblies aside - what would be some good things I could do to this network spec that would make it **VERY DIFFICULT** to understand and make another implementation without the source?

I was thinking some kind of strange hashing approach or some kind of encryption algorithm that would be difficult.

**EDIT** I'm not trying to protect my assemblies or source-code. I'm trying to prevent someone from, for example, watching my protocol with WireShark or similar and then making their own implementation based on that information.

Comment: How about using some encryption?

Comment: @zerkms: Suggested that already in my question

Comment: @caesay: why do you think using some available encryption is difficult, but inventing a new one is easy?

Comment: security through obscurity **does not exist**. At best you can encrypt the connection (ssl etc), but if some has a copy of the client application that is pointless. How much do game manufacturers invest in this? and how long does it take crackers to break in?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I'm not talking about my source-code.

Comment: @caesay Yeah I just noticed, hence I deleted my comments.

Comment: @zerkms: I didn't suggest that.

Comment: @caesay The better question would be, what environment are you going to be in that requires this protection? If it is internal LAN, then you don't need to protect the protocol, but define the network to stop transgression. If it is the internet, take a tried and tested protocol and use that instead.

Comment: @caesay Haha! If you wade through the ream of comments on Cicata's answer, advising to create your own custom solution to encrypting the packets, you will need to obfuscate said code in order to guard against reverse engineering. [The circle is now complete.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCNeJmLAsBo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All right, three cases:

- Users can't access server code and can't access client code: Easiest way is to use a pregenerated shared secret stored in the binary, and aes encrypt/decrypt.
- Users can access client or server code but not both: Use a public/private key method. You can encrypt using the public key but the private one is needed to decrypt.
- Users can access both client and server code: You're screwed.

If you want to improve security, this static key should only be used during session initiation, to generate a new shared secret, which is then used for communication.

Edit: actually, a more easy and safe solution is to use ssl and certificates (it's a mantra that you shouldn't implement your own encryption) Each certificate comes with a secret private key. As long as users don't have access to that you're safe if you verify that the peer has the exact correct certificate.

Comment: Is there actually a case in which clients cannot access client code?

Comment: @Cicada: That's what I was asking myself, too. Does not negate the fact that this is a good answer.

Comment: @caesay Never said it wasn't.

Comment: @Cicada Certainly, if you stick it in your black box hardware. E.g. any current gen game console (granted, they can and have been broken into)

Answer (score 6):

For having reversed a few network protocols (from MMOs), I can tell you that you will *never* protect your protocol for very long, I'm sorry.

The best you can do is:

- Obfuscate it using a *custom* algorithm (because it takes longer to reverse than a known one). Using a known *encryption* scheme offers no protection whatsoever.
- Add noise. Try to be very, very confusing. Add random values that make no sense whatsoever. Try to use a dynamic layout for packets. Move fields. Send useless packets. Just like if it were garbage.
- Version your protocol, so that two consecutive version are incompatible. That can be hard to do, but it obliges the reverser to re-do the work for every subsequent version.

But these are just ways to slow down attackers. It's certainly not going to stop them.

Comment: A custom algorithm as opposed to a known large key algorithm that the FBI can't break into given 1000 years and some luck? Not the best advice IMO.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The custom algorithm isn't there for security, it's there to require more effort on the attacker's part.

Comment: Doesn't more security = more effort? You imply security.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No. Using a known algorithm just requires finding the key. Using a custom one implies reversing it entirely.

Comment: He is right and wrong. It will not improove serious security - it very likely is total crap from an encryption point of view, most people are not even aware of HOW encryptions are cracked. BUt it WILL keep all the script kiddies away and makes it a little harder than just running a network sniffer, and often enough that is worth something.

Comment: @Cicada You assume finding the key is easier than reverse engineering some source code. I prefer to trust a security specialist's implementation other than my own for encryption.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes, finding the key is *always* easier than having to understand how the entire algorithm works. The purpose of customization is just to oblige the attacker to figure how your  entire cryptosystem works, even if it's totally bad (and it probably is).

Comment: @Cicada I am afraid that your argument is nothing more than an assumption. I would farm this part of the system off to someone who knows, personally.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I am afraid not. I can tell you it's so much easier to figure "oh, this program uses AES in ECB mode. Fine." than "what is this? I've never seen before! I'm gonna have to step through it".

Comment: @Cicada Knowing how it does something does not give you all the answers, whereas a custom implementation will have all the answers in the binary. Plus reverse engineering is also a proven way to gain knowledge, otherwise people wouldn't do things like obfuscation in order to make it difficult.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I am merely talking for experience. Knowing how it does implies finding the key, which is basically just observing the stack trace. A custom implementation implies reversing the entire encryption process.

Comment: @Cicada Or simply extracting it and re-using it without actually having to re-implement it. Six and two-threes from my ignorant perspective.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I wish it were that simple. However it's not. Look, the OP wants to make his protocol *very difficult* to understand, and these are my advices, from a reverser standpoint: something weak and unique requires more effort than a secure, well known solution. Period.

Comment: @Adam: I think you are missing the fact that the encryption is not there for transport security, but for protocol obfuscation. However, you're right that the protocol does not even need to be reversed to break it, as you can just extract the original routines to implement it. In so far, I agree that this is just another case where obscurity doesn't buy you much, but has large costs (implementing and maintaining the custom protocol)

Comment: I'd love to see how you make an algorithm in code so obscure that someone couldn't reverse engineer it to see how it works in a disproportionate amount of time to make it not worthwhile. The entire algorithm could boil down to one code file at the end of the day.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Have you heard of Skype? Years in the market, still not reversed. If you're evil enough, you *can* make the reversing of your algorithm very long. Of course it won't last for ever. The goal is just to earn time.

Comment: @Cicada I would not choose a solution because a large company with teams of quality developers and constant live servers can keep themselves safe with it. It is no guarantee. For all you know, their obfuscation mechanism could change per call - they have the benefit of a constantly connected system that the OP may not. My only gripe is the choice of wording of your first point. You may as well suggest he add 1 to all bytes before subtracting 1 at the other end. Even "simple custom" implementations can be false security even if just for obfuscation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The goal is not being *secure* because *you can't be secure*. The goal is to be *as cryptic as possible*. Even substracting one as you say is an option. *No* security. Takes a bit of time to figure. And the goal is to *sum* a maximum of these *bits of time*. I can't help but think you are completely missing my point. Is my wording that bad?

Comment: [Why Isn't My Encryption.. Encrypting?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-isnt-my-encryption-encrypting.html)

Comment: @Cicada My own point is that I see the goal as getting the information out of the packets. If some other clever person has implemented what may be a well known algorithm, even if they know how it is implemented they don't have enough information (or any more than with a custom solution) to continue on to get the actual data. And again to my point L.B that is an example of someone who doesn't do this day-in day-out creating a solution, the problem there wasn't his choice of a well known mechanism, but his usage of it.

Comment: @Cicada I don't disagree with the idea, but the wording. You make it sound like replacing existing, strong mechanisms with something custom is infinitely better. If that were the case, existing mechanisms wouldn't exist. However, the purposes are different. To simply obfuscate is not necessarily to re-imagine well known encryption methods. Funny how this actually boils down to one of my original suggestions in the question comments, to help confuse your own implementation, use [obfuscation](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) lol, I'm done.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth In terms of being *very difficult*, it *is* much better. *Infinitely* is an exaggeration. Again, finding the key for a known algorithm is *trivial*. Reversing a new one, not necessarily. Also yes, that's what I'm suggesting in my post: **obfuscate** instead of **encrypt**. You finally understand! Wooo.

Comment: @Cicada If finding the keys of these encryption mechanisms is so trivial, why do they exist as published solutions to encryption in the first place? I still disagree with your sentiments against the well known ones, but I don't disagree with your proposal of custom obfuscation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Because they assume you don't have access to the key. Which is not the case here.

Comment: @Cicada So where would said access come from? I didn't realise the key was suddenly so accessible in this conversation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth You got me wrong, my point was, even with a well known algorithm how hard it could be to implement a secure protocol.

Comment: @L.B OK, apologies there. I know it isn't a guaranteed secure solution - but I would still initially favour it over something I do myself.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth From the binaries, of course? Either reversing or sniffing. You *have* physical access to one end of the communication. Therefore you *have* the key. Secure algorithms make the assumption that people can only spy from the outside.

Comment: @Cicada I understood the idea behind encryption vs. obfuscation a long while ago, but your post clearly states encryption.

Comment: @Cicada OK so this all assumes that they have physical access to the transport layer, but not necessarily access to the decryption logic. A lot of this is missing from your answer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Granted, I fixed that. And physical access implies decryption logic. You have the binaries. You basically have *everything* you need.

Comment: @Cicada Definitely not necessarily. Physical access to the transport medium is not access to the computer - it is just very likely. I find that as this discussion goes further, more and more assumptions are made. It is disconcerting considering this is a discussion on security. It just **cements** my opinion that if this were critically important I would give it to someone steeped in this experience, perhaps someone from Skype.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No, physical access to one *end* of the communication (sender or receiver), not transport layer (I misread). Also this is not a discussion on *security* but on *obfuscation*. Pretty orthogonal.

Comment: @Cicada The security is against understanding of data packets - do it via obfuscation, it is still trying to achieve security. If they had full access to the other end, why would they not just use your own code to do the decryption - I think it would fall under the "you're screwed" category. Either way, interesting discussion, I learned a lot. But that is me for the evening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11839/discussion-between-cicada-and-adam-houldsworth)

Answer (score 2):

There are three solutions:

1. TLS.
2. SSLv3.
3. Whatever you cook up.

1 and 2 already work.

Answer (score 0):

I am also in the process of writing a network protocol in C#. I have made use of encryption to secure the protocol. Here is the outlay of how I did it, you might find this useful.

- As soon as the client connects the server requests a random UUID from the client, the client encrypts this UUID with a password know to both the server and client.
- All packets sent thereafter by the server or client will encrypted using that UUID as a key.

Regarding "I was thinking some kind of strange hashing approach", hashing is usually only used for data verification. i.e. to ensure it was not modified en-route to you.

Hope this helps.